# Adding game logos to their respective tag

Tags: discussion, tags, design, logo

I think it would be a nice feature to have all game tags, e.g. World of Warcraft, to have their little logo to the left of the tag like on Stack OverFlow with the Adobe logo.

[image] World of Warcraft

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logos on tags represent sponsorship of the tags. Until we get a sponsorship system (and consequently, until those game companies actually sponsor their respective tags), we probably won't see anything like this.

This is probably going to be consistent across the Stack Exchange Network, so to keep in vein with that, we probably will not be allowed to have icons on tags to mean something other than a sponsorship.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for the info.

Comment: What exactly does "sponsoring a tag" entail?  Do they give official answers?

Comment: @bwarner The Meta Stack Overflow explanation could use some work, so I'll just give you a brief rundown - companies may choose to pay Stack Exchange Inc. to "sponsor" a tag. This puts a logo of their choice on the tag, and adds a box on the tag's main page (above the wiki excerpt) which they can provide advertisement links. Sponsorship lasts for a period of time. [Android on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) is a fairly good and long-lasting example.